# Collections.sort gives me an Error by sorting a given Array

Tags: java, collections

I know that I can use "Arrays.sort(temprature);" to sort this 
but I want to know why collection method doesn't work because it has Max, Min, Reverse, etc... in it.

```
import java.util.Collections;
public class sortingTheArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] temprature =  {9,8,5,13,7,17,5,14,9,5,18};

        for (double ar : temprature) {
            System.out.println(ar); 
        }

        Collections.sort(temprature);
        for (double ar : temprature) {
            System.out.println(ar);
        }

        Collections.reverse(temprature);
        for (double ar : temprature) {
            System.out.println(ar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Because an array is not a collection.

Comment: `Collections.sort` requires a `List`, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because you are using `Collections.sort` on an array. An array is not a Java Collection, try using Arrays.sort instead.

Answer (score 0):

1) The name of the class is better to be written with the first letter in uppercase. (convention)

2) You should have provided the error you got.

3) The method does not work because you are calling a Collections method to an array, while Collections works for Lists. To sort an Array you can either convert it to a List or sort it with various sorting methods (Insertion, Selection, Bubble,...).

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array of primitives and we cannot have a list of primitive types(java 7 and below). So First of all change the array

from this `int [] temprature =  {9,8,5,13,7,17,5,14,9,5,18};` to this `Integer[] temprature =  {9,8,5,13,7,17,5,14,9,5,18};`

Now you can change it to a List `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temprature));` and do operations like sort, reverse, max, min etc.

```
public class SortingTheArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer [] temprature =  {9,8,5,13,7,17,5,14,9,5,18};

    for (double ar : temprature) {
        System.out.println(ar); 
    }

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temprature));

    Collections.sort(list);
    for (double ar : list) {
        System.out.println(ar);
    }

    Collections.reverse(list);
    for (double ar : list) {
        System.out.println(ar);
    }

    System.out.println("Max Value : " + Collections.max(list));
    System.out.println("Min Value : " + Collections.min(list));
}
```

}

Edit 1 -
If you are using java 8 you can use Arrays.stream() for creating a list of primitives.

```
int [] temprature2 =  {9,8,5,13,7,17,5,14,9,5,18};
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.stream(temprature2).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```